# Npm pack to include local modules

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json, npm-pack

I have some **local modules** that I want to include in my package to be sent to a server. Since these local packages are not on the npm registry, they need to be **part of the package**.

I have tried some ways to get the node_modules folder included in the package using **npm pack**, however it seems this is not possible at all?

Secondly I tried to list the local modules in the **bundledDepencies** in the package.json file and use **npm pack**, however this also does not include the local modules, no matter what;

```
{
    "name": "dev",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "main.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "local-module": "file:../../local-module"
    },
    "bundledDependencies": [
        "local-module"
    ]
}
```

How can I get these local modules included in the dev package?

The local module does contain **dependencies** itself, not sure if that makes things more complicated?

Comment: Are the local dependencies on GitHub?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing at the moment and it appears to be working. One gotcha is that you need to run `npm install` after configuring the local dependency so that npm creates a link in your node_modules folder to the local-module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue a while back, and a good and simple solution, is just to put your local modules into private git repos (which are now free on GitHub, [thanks Microsoft](https://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/3068940/github-offers-private-code-repository-access-for-free) )

Then, in your `package.json`, just add:

```
"dependencies" : {
  "name1" : "git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish",
  "name2" : "git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish"
}
```

Source, [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

I believe Alicia's approach is the cleanest one. However for someone that runs into the same issue as I did, whereby a server requires a tarball, but does not have git installed, I added my local packages to a seperate folder in the project called repo and referenced them in the package.json as;

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-local-package": "file:./repo/my-local-package"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also [yalc](https://github.com/whitecolor/yalc), which creates a local store for local packages. After adding a local package to the store, you can use yalc to copy the local package into another package. You can also use it to do updates of local packages.